# Strip all matching characters from string

Tags: python

Given any of the following strings:

```
'test'
'test='
'test=='
'test==='
```

I'd like to run a function on it that will remove any/all '=' characters from the end.  Now, I could write something like this in two seconds, in fact, here goes one, and I can imaging a dozen alternative approaches:

```
def cleanup():
    p = passwd()

    while True:
        new_p = p.rstrip('=')

        if len(new_p) == len(p):
            return new_p

        p = new_p
```

**But I was wondering if anything like that already exists as part of the Python Standard Library?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.rstrip()` **already** removes **all** matching characters:

```
>>> 'test===='.rstrip('=')
'test'
```

There is no need to loop.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is `str.rstrip`:

```
>>> 'test'.rstrip('=')
'test'
>>> 'test='.rstrip('=')
'test'
>>> 'test=='.rstrip('=')
'test'
>>> 'test==='.rstrip('=')
'test'
>>>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

> `str.rstrip([chars])`
>
> Return a copy of the string **with trailing characters removed.**

It should be noted however that `str.rstrip` only removes characters from the right end of the string.  You need to use `str.lstrip` to remove characters from the left end and `str.strip` to remove characters from both ends.